# Best practice to send secure data from azure webhook

Tags: azure, api, security, webhooks, azure-logic-apps

Unfamiliar with handling secure data but now I've began working in azure, specifically with a dynamics instance and logic apps. The webhook needs to give the external api secure data such as ssn. What's the best way to go about sending secure data like this over network? Oauth2 is implemented but is there something else I can implement so we are not directly sending the ssn?

Comment: If this what you want?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-securing-a-logic-app#access-to-parameter-inputs

Answer (score 0):

Always using SSL (HTTPS) is a secure way to send data over the wire. I believe a little more added security would be to use [Certificate and Public Key Pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning) if possible.

Also, another way to secure sensitive data would be to first store it in [Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-overview) and share the reference to that secret in your webhook call to the Logic App.

The Logic App would then acquire the secret from Azure Key Vault [using Managed Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-managed-service-identity).